# Visual C# - Program Will Not Run

Tags: visual-studio-2010, c#

I made a program with Visual Studio 2010. It required .NET Framework 4.0 to run, and the machine it needs to run on is not connected to the internet, so I found the redistributable online on my own machine and copied it over.

I installed the software on the machine (it's a very simple program, I just made up an installer to do the .NET installation as well as putting the .exe file of my program into Program Files) but any time I try to run it, I get a Windows Error Report message saying the program failed to run.

Are there any suggestions as to where I could look for the cause of this issue?

(If it matters, the machine I'm trying to run it on is running Windows XP while I am running Windows 7. I don't think this is a compatibility issue though...)

Another thought I had is...how can I check if I'm compiling for 64-bit or 32-bit Windows?

Comment: How about exact error message? Also you should have option to select configuration next to the start debugging button. Looks like green "play" mark. Next to it, you'll find debug/release drop-down menu and x86/configure drop-down menu.

Comment: Does this perhaps belong on stackoverflow?

Comment: @boot13: I guess if we don't figure it out, then yeah.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can check the Windows event log and it might give you some more specific information regarding the error, if you're lucky you'll see a stack trace (depending on whether it was compiled with debug symbols or not).  That might give you a clue; without more details though I don't think we'll be able to help.

Regarding your question about 64 bit vs 32 bit: by default .net applications are agnostic regarding the cpu architecture.  Since the application is JIT'ed to native machine code just before it is run (on the machine it is installed on) this JIT compiler is responsible for this function.  However, in Visual Studio you can override that behavior if you need to.

Answer (score 0):

.NET Framework 4.0 isn't compatible Windows XP Service Pack 2.  .Net Framework 3.5 *might* suffice for your program.